# Using cfhttp to post to an API

Tags: oauth, coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm playing around the [Singly API](https://api.singly.com/) at the moment, and there are ZERO ColdFusion examples (as far as I can see - and I've gone through a *lot* of google search results!)  So, I'm trying to 'fudge' my way through it.

I've hit a stumbling block with something. I suspect it isn't specific to Singly, but I just can't figure out the syntax. I'm specifically stuck on the [authorization](https://singly.com/docs/authorization).  I've gotten as far as doing the second post back, which the docs state:

> You will then make a post back to:
>
> ```
> https://api.singly.com/oauth/access_token
> ```
>
> With the following parameters in the body:
>
> `client_id` Your Singly OAuth 2 client ID
>     `client_secret`
>   Your Singly OAuth 2 client secret
>     `code` the code that was
>   passed back in the URL above

Currently, I keep getting an error "no such app" - I *suspect* this is because I'm not sending the data correctly, because if I manually fire a request (using the same details), it works fine.

The part I'm stuck with is how I go about formatting everything, presumably into a `cfhttpparam` with a type `body`. I'm aware I can only use body type once in a cfhttp call.  There's no indication that the data needs to be sent as JSON etc

Many Thanks

Comment: have you tried passing the client_id and client_secret as type="header" ? I know that's not how they say to do it, but I had a similar issue with an api and that fixed my issue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that didn't work, but it did point me to try sending at as formFields instead - which DID work.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of anyone else searching, Matt Busche suggested sending them as headers.  That didn't work, but did point me to try sending them as formFields, which DID work.  Here's the working code:

```
<cfhttp method="POST" url="https://api.singly.com/oauth/access_token">
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="client_id" value="my_client_id">
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="client_secret" value="my_client_secret">
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="code" value="#url.code#">
</cfhttp>
```